# java to matlab conversion

Tags: java, matlab, hashmap

I am a newbie at matlab . As a part of a larger problem, I need to find maximum number of occurrences of a string in an array of Strings.

Since I have some experience in java I have written the partial code in java ( only until the number of occurences of the string within the string array can be computed I can sort the hashmap depending on the values and extract this)

```
int incr = 0;
    String[] c = { "c1", "c2", "c3", "c1", "c2", "c2", "c2","c1","c2" };
    Map<String, Integer> classRegistry = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
        String classes = c[i];
        if (!(classRegistry.containsKey(classes))) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < c.length; j++) {
                if (classes.equals(c[j])) {
                    incr++;
                }
            }
            classRegistry.put(classes, incr+1);
            incr = 0;
        }
    }
```

Any idea how i can use something like a hashMap in MATLAB to calculate the number of occurrences of all the strings in an array

Thanks,

Bhavya

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MATLAB has a function [TABULATE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/tabulate.html) available in the Statistics Toolbox:

```
c = {'c1' 'c2' 'c3' 'c1' 'c2' 'c2' 'c2' 'c1' 'c2'};
t = tabulate(c)
t = t(:,1:2)
```

The result:

```
t = 
    'c1'    [3]
    'c2'    [5]
    'c3'    [1]
```

Alternatively, you can do the same using the [UNIQUE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/unique.html) and [ACCUMARRAY](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/accumarray.html) functions:

```
c = {'c1' 'c2' 'c3' 'c1' 'c2' 'c2' 'c2' 'c1' 'c2'};
[classes,~,subs] = unique(c);
counts = accumarray(subs(:),1);
```

Again the result as before:

```
>> t = [classes(:) num2cell(counts)]
t = 
    'c1'    [3]
    'c2'    [5]
    'c3'    [1]
```

Then to find the string that occurred the most, use:

```
>> [~,idx] = max(counts);
>> classes(idx)
ans = 
    'c2'
```

Comment: I used the tabulate function and was able to obtain the solution quite easily.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify exaclty how you would want your input and output data types to be, but I wrote this quick script you might find usefull.

```
c = {'c1' 'c2' 'c3' 'c1' 'c2' 'c2' 'c2' 'c1' 'c2'};
count = struct();
for ic=1:length(c)
    field = c{ic};
    if isfield(count, field)
        count = setfield(count, field, getfield(count, field) + 1);
    else
        count = setfield(count, field, 1);
    end
end
```

The output for this specific `c` would be

```
count =

    c1: 3
    c2: 5
    c3: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have experience with Java, you could just write your code in Java and call it from MATLAB.  [This techdoc article](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_external/f44062.html) should help you get started if you decide to go this route.  But it would probably be more useful to learn how to do it in m-script (see jomb87's answer)

Incidentally, you could improve the performance of your Java algorithm if you take further advantage of the hash map:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
        String classes = c[i];
        if (classRegistry.containsKey(classes)) {
            classRegistry.put(classes, classRegistry.get(classes) + 1);
        } else {
            classRegistry.put(classes, 1);
        }
    }
```